How to create SEO friendly URL through .htaccess code for php site
I have to make the URL of my site a SEO friendly URL and I tried some .htaccess code but it didn't happen. currently the URL of my site is this:- https://www.sarkariresultz.net/postview.php?id=latest-jobs/sbi-specialist-officers-so-various-post-recruitment-2024
But I want the site's URL to be like this:https://www.sarkariresultz.net/latest-jobs/sbi-specialist-officers-so-various-post-recruitment-2024
RewriteEngine On
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)$ postview.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]


You want to revise your question. There is an "edit" button below it. Use it ... Currently the actual and the desired form of the URL are identical.

Also you seem to have copied some rules using some editor that backslash-escapes things in a manner that will break things. Remove all those backslashes apart from the literal dots in the file name extension ".php" which indeed should be escaped as ".php" and the "\s" as special char that matches any white space character.

OK, thanks for revising the question. You could have said so ;-)

That would be a general form of what you probably look for:
RewriteEngine On
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ /postview.php?id=$1 [L]

That will rewrite any incoming request that does not directly point to an existing file or folder to your script postview.php and hand over the actually requested path as HTTP GET parameter "id".
Such rule can be implemented in the central http server's host configuration. Alternatively, if you do not have access to that, you can use a distributed configuration file (typically called ".htaccess"), if that feature is enabled in the central configuration . Such file needs to be readable for the http server process and it has to be located in the folder configured as DocumentRoot for your http host.
Maybe you also want to add a rule to externally redirect clients requesting the old, existing URL scheme to the new one you suggest. So some combination like that:
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/?postview\.php$ /%1 [R=301,L]

Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ /postview.php?id=$1 [L]

It might be that you need to implement exceptions from that general rule. We cannot say. If so, then you need to implement exception rules before that general rule, so further up in that file.
